# How to show that the following formula isn't valid in first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm trying to understand how I can solve this task.
I need to show that the following formula isn't valid in first order logic:

∀x(Px∨Qx) → ∀xPx∨∀xQx

I would appreciate if someone could show me how I can solve it. Thank you very much

Comment: Hint: how about a counterexample?

Comment: Perhaps some sort of condition that applies to some numbers but not others?

Comment: Imagine you have a box with red(P) and blue(Q) marbles, what would be the truth-value of both sides of your implication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would appreciate if someone could show me how I can solve it.

The formula $\forall x~(Px\vee Qx)\to ((\forall x~Px)\vee (\forall x~Qx))$ may be declared invalid if there is some interpretation for the domain and predicates where where $\forall x~(Px\vee Qx)$ is true but *neither* $\forall x~Px$ *nor* $\forall x~Qx$ are true (ie: both are false).

Thus what you need to do is to show that this is so.   You should try *constructing* such an interpretation; a counterexample — a domain with predicates P and Q such that: everything is either P or Q, but something is not P and something is not Q.